# The current node list is empty php scraping

Tags: php, goutte, domcrawler

I am having an issue getting an image from a page.  Some pages have it some don't. On the ones that don't i get the `current node list is empty` error.

I am doing `!empty($crawler->filter('.listing-logo > img')->attr('src'))` but it still returns the exception.

I've tried doing it with a `->count()` but it won't allow that on a string.  I've also used `strlen` but it still sends back the empty.

```
$client = new Goutte\Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', $item->data['child']['']['guid'][0]['data']);
dd(!empty($crawler->filter('.listing-logo > img')->attr('src')));
```

Comment: show you code, and are you using any library for crawling?

Comment: Edited to show my code

Comment: I am using this try this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm